# How can I know if my car was added to SENTRI?

Tags: borders, global-entry, trusted-traveler, sentri

During the [SENTRI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SENTRI) interview, it was not clear to me whether (or not) the officer processed all paperwork and added the vehicle. I did not find a chance to ask while at the office.

Below are two screenshots showing what my ttp dashboard looks like... Does it mean that the vehicle is good to go?

[image: Main dashboard]

[image: Link from Manage Vehicle]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your vehicle has been registered, and you are good to go.

Two months ago I renewed my Global Entry membership, and as part of that process I registered my car for SENTRI.

Several weeks later, I logged into the main CBP page, followed the "Manage Vehicles" link, and was shown a vehicle info page that was identical to yours, save that it displayed my vehicle's info rather than yours. I assume you blocked out your vehicle's actual info in the screen shots. Other than the info difference, your CBP pages look just the same.